# Выборка сообщений

Tags: php

Делаю сообщения на сайте, но пока что не получается: нужно сделать выборку - видимо неправильно делаю: я хочу выбрать сообщения между двумя людьми:

```sql
SELECT `id`, `to_id`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `type`, `text`
FROM `messages` 
WHERE (`owner_id` = :owner_id AND `to_id` = :to_id) 
   OR (`owner_id` = :to_id AND `to_id` = :owner_id)
```

`to_id` - это id моего адресата
`owner_id` - мой id

Выводятся сообщения как одинаковые. Не подскажите, как изменить?

Comment: что значит  выводятся как одинаковые?

Comment: Покажите результат выборки из БД фотографией или таблицей.